# Symfony 3 Deployment on Heroku fails

Tags: heroku, symfony

I wanted to try to deploy a Symfony 3 application to Heroku, but I get a deployment failure.

I have set the environment SYMFONY_ENV variable to "prod", created a Procfile with the following content:

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

And finally I installed the nodejs and php buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
```

Shortly before the deployment is finished I get the following:

http://pastebin.com/LUBvVMxF

Anyone have an idea why suddenly the bin/console cli tool can't access?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my .gitignore file was not the right one for the Symfony application in version 3. The file "bin/console" was on the .gitignore so it was not checked out on the heroku dyno...